# Symplectic submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

Which symplectic submanifolds can be realized in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$? It easy to show that such submanifolds aren't compact. So, they are spheres with some handles and holes.
Which relations between the numbers of holes and handles do exist?

Comment: you didn't mention that you had cross-posted this to MO! Next time, be sure to mention it when you do, so we don't waste time duplicating effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None.

By Moser, the only invariants of a symplectic surface are its topological type and its total volume.

Suppose we can embed some surface of genus $g$ and $b$ boundary components as a symplectic manifold of area $A$. Then, you can embed it as a submanifold of arbitrary area by scaling $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Now suppose we can embed a surface of genus $G$ and any number of boundary components. Then, for any $g \le G$ and $b$ arbitrary, we can embed a symplectic surface of genus $g$ and $b$ boundary points by cutting out a sub-surface.

Finally, we observe that I can embed a surface of genus $G$ large by taking a degree $d$ holomorphic curve in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ ( so $G = \frac{1}{2} (d-1)(d-2)$ ) and deleting a small neighbourhood of the $\mathbb{C}P^1$ at $\infty$. Holomorphic implies symplectic, so we're done.

More generally, Gromov tells us that symplectic embeddings of codimension 2 open symplectic manifolds satisfy an h-principle. In other words, there are no obstructions other than homotopic ones.

Comment: You are misstating Moser's theorem: With your formulation, it applies only to compact manifolds. In the noncompact case, the correct reference is Greene and Shiohama, "Diffeomorphisms and volume-preserving embeddings of noncompact manifolds", TAMS, 1979. The correct statement involves finiteness/infiniteness of volumes of ends. This paper also answers OP's question.

Comment: @studiosus: Thank you for the corrected reference. In this case, since the surfaces are compact with boundary, I think it's possible to make some minor modifications to Moser so that it works. In particular, I believe you can modify Moser's proof by hand to make the flow of the vector field he constructs be defined up to time 1. Since that's the piece where compactness is necessary, I think everything else should carry through.

Comment: As I said, for noncompact surfaces there are more invariants than just the total volume. For instance, compact surface surface with two holes (disks removed) are the same surface with a hole an a puncture are not simplectomorphic.

Comment: @studiosus: your example isn't relevant to my claim because the punctured surface isn't a manifold with boundary. However, I think you are right that the actions on the boundary are relevant. I'll adjust my answer accordingly. Thank you.